Conflict between webpack OptimizePlugin and bootstrap 5 components (tooltip, tab)
I try to set up webpack configuration with separate downloads for modern and legacy browsers according to this principle
<script src="modern.main.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="legacy.main.js" nomodule defer></script>

For this purpose, on the recommendation from Google Wiki, I added to the configuration Optimize Plugin for Webpack but when loading the page and interacting with bootstrap elements, I get errors in the console that signal a conflict in the resulting build.


const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { WebpackManifestPlugin } = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
//const HtmlWebpackEsmodulesPlugin = require('webpack-module-nomodule-plugin');
//const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizePlugin = require('optimize-plugin');

require('default-passive-events');
require('dotenv').config();

// Common configuration
const commonConfig = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
    publicPath: process.env.PUBLIC_PATH || path.join('/', path.relative(process.cwd(), path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'))),
    assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[name][ext]',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      /*
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                {
                  useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                  corejs: 3, // Use core-js@3
                },
              ],
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      */
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        exclude: [/font-awesome\.min\.css$/, /sow-slider\.css$/],
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              url: false,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader', // Add postcss-loader
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [
                  require('autoprefixer')
                ],
              },
            },
          },
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /(font-awesome\.min\.css|sow-slider\.css)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|svg)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'fonts/[name][ext][query]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'images/[name][ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /modernizr-config\.json$/,
        use: [
          'modernizr-loader',
          'json-loader'
        ],
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      modernizr$: path.resolve(__dirname, ".modernizrrc"),
    },
    fallback: {
      "assert": require.resolve("assert/"),
      "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
      "fs": false,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      ItcSlider: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/vendor/itc-slider.min.js')
    }),
    new WebpackManifestPlugin({
      fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './src/index.html',
      inject: 'body',
    }),
    new OptimizePlugin({
      exclude: [
        /node_modules\/bootstrap/
      ]
    }),
  ],
  stats: {
    errorDetails: true
  },
  mode: 'production',
};

module.exports = commonConfig;



Errors occur in this fragment of the script.js with tooltips and tabs. If the tabs are switched despite the error, then the tooltips don't appear at all. Otherwise the assembly works properly.
import { Tooltip, Tab } from 'bootstrap';

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'));
    var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
        if (tooltipTriggerEl.closest('.vertical-slider-left')) {
            var options = { boundary: tooltipTriggerEl.closest('.vertical-slider-left') };
            return new Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl, options);
        } else {
            return new Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl); // Default options if closest() fails
        }
    });

    var tabTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#v-pills-tab button[data-bs-toggle="pill"]'));
    var tabList = tabTriggerList.map(function (tabTriggerEl) {
        tabTriggerEl.addEventListener('shown.bs.tab', function (event) {
            for (var i = 0; i < tabTriggerList.length; i++) {
              if(tabTriggerList[i].classList.contains('prev')) {
                tabTriggerList[i].classList.remove('prev');
              }
            }
            if(event.relatedTarget.id<event.target.id) {
                document.getElementById(event.relatedTarget.id).classList.add("prev");
            }
        });
    });

});

If I connect scripts and all libraries separately without webpack build, then everything works properly. npm, bootstrap and other libraries and plugins are installed latest versions. I tried to achieve similar functionality with babel-loader, but without success and even Chat GPT didn't help me here. What can you advise me?
